# React MUI: Create stacked progress bar by disabling buffer animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, progress-bar

[image: Buffering progress bar]

I want a stacked progress bar tracking two fields:

1. `valueBuffer`: amount unlocked out of total. The light blue bar.
2. `value`: amount claimed out of unlocked. The dark blue bar.

Variant `buffered` suits my use case but the dotted line animation is annoying. How do I disable the animation and replace it with a regular bar?

```
<LinearProgress variant="buffer" value={50} valueBuffer={70} />
```

If this is not possible, what is the alternative to have a [bootstrap style stacked progress bar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/#stacked)?

[image: bootstrap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add a custom style to `.MuiLinearProgress-dashed` and modify the default dashed styles using `sx` attribute like this:

```
<LinearProgress
    variant="buffer"
    value={progress}
    valueBuffer={buffer}
    sx={{
      "& .MuiLinearProgress-dashed": {
        backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
        backgroundImage: "none",
        animation: "none"
      }
    }}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-progress-custom-buffer-thxnhl?file=/demo.tsx) for a live working example of this solution.